# How to Stop gradle task from executing on every gradle reload

Tags: gradle

```
task('copytask', type: Copy) {
    def SRC_FOLDER = "$rootDir"
    def DEST_FOLDER = 'C:\\Users\\IdeaProjects\\destfolder'
    copy {
        from("$SRC_FOLDER\\controller\\app")
        into("$DEST_FOLDER\\controller\\app")
    }
}
```

This is my small Gradle task to copy.
Whenever I am reloading/refreshing my Gradle or starting my IDEA this task is executing, i want this task to execute only when I call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your task is not really executing. Instead, your task is getting configured, but during configuration you are copying using the [`copy`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#copy-groovy.lang.Closure-) method of the [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) instance. Your actual task `copytask` of type [`Copy`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) remains unconfigured and won't do anything, even if it would be executed.

Change your code and remove the `copy` method and the files should only be copied when running the task `copytask`:

```
task('copytask', type: Copy) {
    def SRC_FOLDER = "$rootDir"
    def DEST_FOLDER = 'C:\\Users\\IdeaProjects\\destfolder'
    from("$SRC_FOLDER\\controller\\app")
    into("$DEST_FOLDER\\controller\\app")
}
```

Comment: i am using copy bcoz i want to copy from multiple sources to multiple destinations like this -        copy {
            from("$SRC_FOLDER\\controller\\app")
            into("$DEST_FOLDER\\controller\\app")
        }
        copy {
            from("$SRC_FOLDER\\database\\src")
            into("$DEST_FOLDER\\database\\src")
        }

Comment: If a `Copy` task cannot satisfy your requirements, either create multiple `Copy` tasks (you can do it in a loop) or create a regular task (without `type: Copy`) and call the `copy` method in a `doFirst` / `doLast` closure. This will prevent the execution during configuration phase.